# 'Illegal Offset Type" suddenly occurring in registration array Laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-4

In my registration store function which is called after the user has typed in valid information I have a default array that is converted to JSON and stored in my DB with the user. All of a sudden I am getting the error:

```
Illegal Offset Type (line 50)
```

which the last object of my first array (it is multi dimensional). I deleted the object to see if the error was specific to that object but the error still persists. I don't understand where this error is coming from because I did't change anything in or around the registration system for a while.

This is the store() function being called after the registration form is submitted:

```
public function store()
{
    $input = Input::only('username', 'email', 'password', 'password_confirmation');

    $this->registrationForm->validate($input);

    $user = User::create($input);

    $arr = array(
        [1] => array(
            'name' => 'Apple',
            'time' => '2:00 am',
            'date' => '10.26.96',
            'symptom' => false,),
        [2] =>array(
            'name' => 'Banana',
            'time' => '3:56 pm',
            'date' => '10.26.96',
            'symptom' => false,),
        [3] =>array(
            'name' => Input::get('symptom'),
            'time' => '4:45 pm',
            'date' => '10.26.96',
            'symptom' => true,
        ));

    $user->json = json_encode($arr);

    $user->save();

    Auth::login($user);

    return Redirect::home();
}
```

The error occurs in "line 50" which is in the last object of the first array `'symptom' => false,),`

I have absolultley no idea how this happened. I even used time machine to load my project from a few days ago when I am certain it was fully functional and the error is still there. I will appreciate any help, please let me know if more information is needed.

Comment: You don't want to wrap your key names in `[...]`

Comment: Wow. That worked completely. I don't remember ever having them unwrapped so its strange that it worked before but not now. You should put that as an answer

Comment: I don't see how it would work any other way. Shazam that's how it's done!  I was just thinking to myself, looking at it, is that a print_r representation or the actual array, then I saw the comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`array` initialization syntax only accept key names as a plain scalar values, thus having `['foo']` syntax is incorrect in this case.